# Getting specific part of a data-attribute on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a div with a data-attribute which has several double quotes inside it, so the information is therefore not escaped, but it is necessary to do it this way in my project.

I am trying to get the "jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim" value when i hover on the div.

```
<div class="test" data-layer-promotion-view="{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}"></div>
```

This is the jQuery which i wrote:

```
$( ".test" ).hover(function() {
  var contentAsset = $(this).attr("data-layer-promotion-view");
  console.log(contentAsset)
});
```

Is there some way to select a certain set of double quotes inside a data-attribute?

See codePen here: http://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/evMLww?editors=1111

Comment: Try change `data-layer-promotion-view="{` to `data-layer-promotion-view='{`

Comment: Since data contains the perfect JSON. You can call `JSON.parse()` on it and can access the attributes.

Comment: Why don't you escape double quotes like this: `\"`? That should work.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia How would I go about doing this? can you make an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use combination of `'` and `"` quotes, then you can use [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve it.

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

```js
var data = $('.test').data('layer-promotion-view');
console.log(data.row_type);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-layer-promotion-view='{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}'></div>
```

Comment: Hi Satpal I cant get this example to work on my codepen, do i need something more?

Comment: @MikkelFennefoss, it's because you're still not correctly escaping the value of the attribute. Now you have `data-layer-promotion-view='"{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}"'`

Comment: and it should really be `data-layer-promotion-view='{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}'` (observe the start and end quotes difference). You can also check my answer if you want a solution for `hover()` using `attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use single quote, when defining attribute

```
<div class="test" data-layer-promotion-view='{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( ".test" ).hover(function() {
  var contentAsset = $(this).attr("data-layer-promotion-view");
  console.log(contentAsset);
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding:10px;
  background: red;
}
.test:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-layer-promotion-view);
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-layer-promotion-view='{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}'>
```

> **Note :** There is an error for using `"`. View your page source code in Browser, You will understand the error for declaring `HTML` attribute. Your attribute string is invalid for using `"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add single quotes instead of double quotes arround the attribute `data-layer-promotion-view` value to correctly escape it and then use `JSON.parse()` to parse the string into an object, no need to change `attr()` to `data()`:

```js
$(".test").hover(function() {
  var contentAsset = JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-layer-promotion-view"));
  console.log(contentAsset.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-layer-promotion-view='{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}'>test</div>
```